# Python error message with OpenLayers Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have just recently downloaded QGIS version 1.9.90-Alpha, Alpha, 5155176. I then went to install the OpenLayers plugin.  That successfully downloaded and installed, or so I thought, but when I went to use it I get an error message.

It says the TypeError is: `sip.methoddescriptor` object is not callable

Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix it?  I am using Python version 2.5.2

This is the error:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/czuck/.qgis/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 48, in addLayer
    self.__plugin.addLayer(self)
  File "C:/Users/czuck/.qgis/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 197, in addLayer
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable
```

Python version:
2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.9.90-Alpha Alpha, 5155176

Python path:

`['C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python', 'C:/Users/czuck/.qgis/python', 'C:/Users/czuck/.qgis/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\python25.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-dev\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-dev\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']`

Comment: Where did you get the open layers plugin from?

Comment: Through the fetch Python plugins within Quantum...I think the repositories are set to sourcepole and QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I waited for the update to 2.0, and the OpenLayers plugin now works with 2.0!  I would suggest to anyone having a similar issue that I had, just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial version of the OpenLayers plug-in (for Master) here:

http://www.qgis.nl/2013/06/30/english-temporary-fix-for-openlayers-plugin/?lang=en

It works on my system (QGIS Master/Ubuntu 12.04).

N.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the API for QGIS 2.0 has [changed](http://nathanw.net/2013/06/13/new-qgis-20-api/) and therefore the plugins that worked for 1.8 will not work in 2.0. I don't know what the status for openlayers is for the QGIS 2.0 release but you can read some of the discussion [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Openlayers-plugin-in-2-0-Was-QGIS-2-0-release-and-plugins-td5060364.html).

Comment: I had found another thread later the next day talking about that, didn't realize it was broken for earlier versions right now!  Thanks for letting me know, though! :)